# google chrome console log displays a string with an arrow in it what is that character?

Tags: html, google-chrome, console

i added an image with the console log here it is:
[image]

can someone help me understand what is that arrow by the end of the word phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Chrome will show you the normally non-printable character sequence CR+LF (carriage return + line feed) in a string within a javascript object.

There are severaly ways to reproduce this, including:

Decimal using string class

`console.log({field: "phone" + String.fromCharCode(13) + String.fromCharCode(10)});`

ASCII hex

`console.log({field: "phone" + '\x0d' + '\x0a'});`

Unicode hex

`console.log({field: "phone" + '\u000d' + '\u000a'});`

So basically this is a string containing a newline.